# Unable to change value of global var

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Edit: Had to repost this because someone marked it as a duplicate and linked to an irrelevant question about returning the value of asynchronous functions, which did not help.

I've been stuck on this most of the day. I have a global var user_dict that I initiate with a value, then try to change within a function. The value just won't change.

Using the watch list while debugging, I created a video showing what I mean. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on here?

https://streamable.com/o498yu

I know I need to include code with external links, but the problem isn't reproducible without providing access to my Firebase database hence the video. This is the relevant part of my code though.

When debugging line by line, getUserDict() returns "none_found" as it should, but the value of user_dict never changes. I need getUserDict() to finish before checkUserDict(), but I can't get the promise to work.

```
var user_dict
userLogin()

function userLogin() {
    console.log('userLogin')
    if (checkLogin()) {
        console.log('userLogin checkLogin is true')
        user_dict = getUserDict().then(checkUserDict())
    }
}

function getUserDict() {
    let current_user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    let snapshot = firebase.database().ref().child('profile').child(current_user_id).child('user_dict').once('value')
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        return snapshot.val()
    } else {
        return 'none_found'
    }
}

function checkUserDict() {
    if (user_dict === 'none_found') {
        console.log('userLogin unable to find user_dict, preparing needed data')
        user_dict = getQuestions().then(createProfile())
    } else {
        console.log('userLogin user_dict is ', user_dict)
        handleWelcome(is_first_time = false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t do it, that’s a free ticket to chaos. Currently you cannot change the value later on you won’t  know why it changed, working with side effects is an anti pattern

Comment: What shouldn't I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't waiting for the promises to resolve which is why it's just blowing through and nothing is changing. You can use `async/await` or `then/catch` to make your code wait and update in the order you want.

Here's how it can work using `then/catch` as you're already tyring to implement that pattern.

```js
var user_dict
userLogin()

function userLogin() {
  console.log('userLogin')
  if (checkLogin()) {
    console.log('userLogin checkLogin is true')
    getUserDict().then((value) => {
      // See NOTE below for what "value" is here
      user_dict = value
      checkUserDict()
    })
  }
}

// NOTE
// This function will now wait for Firebase to return and then this
// function will return the snapshot value or a string of `none_found`
function getUserDict() {
  const current_user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid 
  return firebase.database().ref().child('profile').child(current_user_id).child('user_dict').once('value').then(snapshot => {
    if( snapshot.exists ) {
      return snapshot.val()
    }
    return 'none_found'
  })
}

function checkUserDict() {
  if (user_dict === 'none_found') {
    console.log('userLogin unable to find user_dict, preparing needed data')
    user_dict = getQuestions().then(createProfile())
  } else {
    console.log('userLogin user_dict is ', user_dict)
    handleWelcome(is_first_time = false)
  }
}
```

I changed your existing code to make it work, but I would also like to point out that it's generally a bad practice to use globals when scoping a variable is an option. I don't know enough about your other functions to write a correct example, but you can look into variable scope and promise chaining to help.

Comment: Probably worth highlighting that `checkUserDict()` also doesn't handle its `undefined` state if it is called too early.

Comment: Thanks, thought it didn't work but I realized I was still trying to assign the value of getUserDict to another variable and wasn't using your exact syntax, it's working now.